# How can I apply same operation between many columns in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I need to apply the logical OR '|' between many columns and generate a new column in pyspark. What is the best way to do this when you many columns with boolean values and there is need to generate a result column which is the logical OR of all the columns. For example if I have a data frame df

```
data = [(True,False,True),
         (False,False,True),
         (True,True,True),
       (False,True,False),
       (True,False,False)]
     df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(['ID', 'date'])

+-----+-----+-----+
|    a|    b|    c|
+-----+-----+-----+
| true|false| true|
|false|false| true|
| true| true| true|
|false| true|false|
| true|false|false|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

How can I add a  column 'd' as below by applying logical OR

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    a|    b|    c|    d|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| true|false| true| true|
|false|false| true| true|
| true| true| true| true|
|false| true|false| true|
| true|false|false| true|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the input columns in a list and use `reduce` to construct dynamically the logical expression. Then assign the results to a new columns.

Here's the implementation:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as f
>>> data
[(True, False, True), (False, False, True), (True, True, True), (False, True, False), (True, False, False)]
>>> df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> df.show()
+-----+-----+-----+
|    a|    b|    c|
+-----+-----+-----+
| true|false| true|
|false|false| true|
| true| true| true|
|false| true|false|
| true|false|false|
+-----+-----+-----+
>>> columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> df.withColumn('and', reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [f.col(c) for c in columns])).show()
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    a|    b|    c|  and|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| true|false| true|false|
|false|false| true|false|
| true| true| true| true|
|false| true|false|false|
| true|false|false|false|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+

>>> df.withColumn('or', reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [f.col(c) for c in columns])).show()
+-----+-----+-----+----+
|    a|    b|    c| or|
+-----+-----+-----+----+
| true|false| true|true|
|false|false| true|true|
| true| true| true|true|
|false| true|false|true|
| true|false|false|true|
+-----+-----+-----+----+
```

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks.  I used df.withColumn('or', reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [f.col(c) for c in df.columns])).show()

Answer (score 0):

takes a Boolean Column as its condition. When using PySpark, it's often useful to think "Column Expression" when you read "Column".

Logical operations on PySpark columns use the bitwise operators:

- & for and
- | for or
- ~ for not

When combining these with comparison operators such as <, parenthesis are often needed.

In your case, the correct statement is:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn('d',
F.when((df.a == "true") | (df.b == 'true') | (df.c == "true"), "true").otherwise(df.d))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I was looking for something that can apply the operations across several columns, where I don't have to manually enter each of the  columns in a when clause.